# WPF - UserControls very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, propertygrid

I am designing something similar a PropertyGrid where I want to show properties of objects. For special reasons I am not going to use the PropertyGrid but create my own.

For each property I have created a custom usercontrol. Now to my horror the performance is very bad. If I have something like 100 properties it takes 500 milliseconds to show them in a StackPanel/Listbox.

I did an experiment where I add 200 default UserControls to a StackPanel. It took about 50 milliseconds. Still a very high number I think.

Should I not use usercontrols for such a purpose? It seems very object-oriented to do it this way and I can not really see another solution.

However I can see that PropertyGrid and TreeView performs good, so what have they done and what should I do?

**Edit:**

```
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        using (var suspend = Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
        {
            // Add all children here
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                this.propertiesStackPanel.Children.Add(new System.Windows.Controls.Button(){Content = "Testing"});
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
```

This still takes about 50 milliseconds. If I change to my own custom usercontrol it is much higher. I might add that scrolling is not a problem.

**Edit2:**

OK. It has nothing to do with stackpanel. I have found out that it is because creating UserControls is a very expensive operation. If you have any other idea of what to do I would gladly hear them :)

**Edit3:**
Nothing is going on in the constructor of my usercontrol other than InitializeComponent method. Here is an example of a usercontrol I am adding.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="PropertyBox.GroupUC"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Background="#FF32B595" BorderThickness="0">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20px"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="0,1" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </Border>
    <Label x:Name="groupNameLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Label" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="expandButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="12" Height="12" Content="" Click="ExpandButtonClick" Margin="4,0,0,0" Padding="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" d:IsHidden="True"/>
    <Image x:Name="expandButton2" Visibility="Hidden"  Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: hello dude . i have similar problem. Rendering was fast but creation PAINFULLY slow. Still no solution found

Answer (score 6):

My suspicion is that you're triggering many layout updates while adding your hundreds of children.

If that is the bottleneck, you may want to consider doing:

```
using(var suspend = Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
{
       // Add all children here
}
```

This will cause the dispatcher to stop processing messages while you add your controls, and do the entire layout and render in one pass at the end.

Comment: Looks promising! Will reply within the next 24 hours when I have had the chance to test it and tell you the result.

Comment: @bobjink: Interesting - is your UserControl doing work in its constructor?  Can you post the code showing what you're doing during construction/add?